# Are there any instances in the original Spawn comic where he replenishes his Necro counter?

Tags: spawn

In the *Spawn* comic, Necroplasm is a will-controlled magical substance created by the Grand-Mal Demon known as Leviathan. Necroplasm is one way that the otherworldly material and energies of Hell may manifest physically in the Earthly plane. Spawn (Al Simmons), symbiotic suit is itself supposedly necroplasm-based, and interacts with his fully necroplasm powered body, endowing him with superhuman strength, density, weight, healing factor, and metabolism. The suit is a living symbiotic organism which provides him with various powers and great protection, *without* costing him any Necro energy. He can also shoot beams of green necroplasmic energy from his body, or use it to power magical attacks such as teleportation, possession, mind reading and spells.

[image: Spawn in space with his cape floating along with chains and a massive gun on his back]

Al, like all Hellspawn, was created with a limited amount of necroplasmic energy reserves contained within their bodies, measured as 9,999 units to begin with. Once this energy is consumed, their time on Earth ends and the Hellspawn returns to Hell, his soul forfeit. This "counter" would be represented on page in  comic essentially as it appears below. It was somewhat unclear if Al himself would "feel" his reserves dropping, like a power drain, or how a gun gets lighter as it runs out of ammo... but he was made aware of the fact that if he used up all his necroplasmic energy, he'd "die" and be sent back to hell.

[image: A green counter on a black background reading "3:2:6:2"]

This came with a few caveats, though:

1. Normal physical abilities like his strength, speed, and agility wouldn't use these Necro units, so al could fight hand to hand almost indefinitely with his enhanced abilities without sacrificing energy.
2. His suit, K-7 Leetha, had its *own* energy source separate from his. so his suit could do a lot of the heavy damage with its chains, spikes, cape and other weaponry, even arguably "big feats", and not drain his powers.
3. Al was said to be able to "Feed on the evil auras of other beings" to heal or regenerate himself. It's unclear though, if this would be merely to *counteract damage* he may have taken, or more to "replenish" his magic, and thus have the same effect.

So I was curious if there were any instances in the *Spawn* comic where  we see his counter go *up* after he absorbed energy from enemies or some other circumstances? I know his powers were altered a few times, and a new Hellspawn even took over, but still, I can recall no instances when Al himself or someone else noted he had used a necroplasmic power, but had "Recovered" the energy.

If a scan is available, please post copy there of or a link to the pages.

Comment: Issue #300 had him run down to 0 and then come back with a full counter in #301 if I'm reading the summaries right, but I don't think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: https://bleedingcool.com/comics/the-future-of-spawn-after-300-spoilers/

Comment: @FuzzyBoots It would _help,_ though. Did they give any _reason_ as to how he was "Fully restocked"?  I was under the impression when it run out, he _died;_ end of story.  Did he have an "extra life" or something that allowed him to come back fully refreshed and ready to play?  Did Al somehow load in a quarter into the game or something?